# Why isn't preventDefault preventing my page from reloading?

Tags: javascript, preventdefault

I am writing a chat application, in the form of a custom element, in vanilla Javascript, but in every time I submit a message (I have not gone about implementing the actual sending the message yet, so this should be easy) the page reloads.

My HTML for the message form is like this:

```
      <template id="chatapptemplate">
        <form hidden id="messageForm">
          <textarea></textarea>
          <input type="submit" value="Send message">
        </form>
      </template>
```

The MRE for the custom element is like this:

```
customElements.define('chat-app', class chatApp extends HTMLElement {
  constructor () {
    super()
    this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' })
    const chatAppTemplate = document.querySelector('#chatapptemplate')
    this.shadowRoot.appendChild(chatAppTemplate.content.cloneNode(true))
    this.messageForm = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('#messageForm')

    this.messageDetails = {
      'data': 'This object contains more fields, but this is enough for my example.'
    }
  }

  connectedCallback () {
      this.messageForm.addEventListener('submit', this.messageWasSubmitted)
  }

  disconnectedCallback () {
    this.messageForm.removeEventListener('submit', 
    this.messageWasSubmitted)
  }

  messageWasSubmitted = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    e.stopImmediatePropagation()
    const message = e.target.firstElementChild.value
    this.messageDetails['data'] = message
    console.log(this.messageDetails)
    
    if (message.length > 0) {
      e.target.firstElementChild.value = ''
    }
  }
})
```

I never get to see the console log, because the page immediately reloads when I click submit. What could be the reason? I hope I included the right amount of code to reproduce it.

Comment: Check the "preserve log" box so that the console doesn't clear when it reloads. Is the `messageWasSubmitted` handler actually getting called? This can also be found out by placing a breakpoint. If it isn't, was the `connectedCallback` called at all? Is the `messageForm` the expected element?

Comment: Thank you a lot! Putting a breakpoint showed me that the handler was never called.

The reason for this is not apparent in the part of the code you see here, but I only added the event listener if the user had not submitted a username, which I already had done. I meant to add it if it was already defined.

Such a silly miss, but now it works! @Bergi